# Need to run this .bat file for a specific folder

Tags: batch-file

I need to update this so that it can run it on for a specific folder. Lets say for example in `C:\Folder`. I want for the `.bat` to be able to run anywhere but will always do it for the folder in my `C:` drive. Right now this is the best I was able to come up with, this basically needs to be in the folder where I want the results to be at.

```
@echo off 

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d') do echo %%~na>>Filenames.txt

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "txt="
set input=Filenames.txt

for /f "delims=" %%a in (%input%) do (
  set "txt=!txt!%%a, "
)
set "txt=!txt:~0,-2!"
>Comma.txt echo !txt!
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `'dir C:\Folder /b /a-d'` then?

Comment: You could do this all in one `FOR` command.  No reason to output to a text file first.

Comment: It's because I was not the one who made the code. It was passed on to me and I dont know how to updated it based on what I need it to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably wanting to do this. *Please ensure your chosen/known source folder is inserted in place of `%SystemDrive%\Folder` on line `4` before running it*:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "SourceDir=%SystemDrive%\Folder"

Set "FilesList="
(For /F Tokens^=*^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('
 Dir "%SourceDir%" /B /A:-D 2^>NUL') Do (Echo %%G
    If Not Defined FilesList (
        Set "FilesList="%%G"") Else (SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        For /F "Tokens=* Delims=" %%H In ("!FilesList!") Do (EndLocal
            Set "FilesList=%%H,"%%G"")))) 1>"FolderListing.txt"
If Not Defined FilesList (Del "%~dp0FolderListing.txt"
    GoTo :EOF)
(Echo %FilesList%) 1>"%~dp0FolderListing.csv"
```

In this example, as long as the location defined in line `4` exists and has at least one file, this should create two files along side the batch file itself, *(subject to appropriate write permissions)*. One named `FolderListing.csv` containing a single record with comma separated doublequoted fields; and one named `FolderListing.txt` containing each file listed one per line.

Comment: Thanks for the reply everyone. I do need two output as I need the result one in a comma separated format and the other one arranged in a row. So please help me out as I am not knowledge about this things and I am just asking help to update this code so that I can be ran anywhere but will always be for a specific folder path. Thank you.

Comment: @burniksapwet, I have replaced the two examples in my answer to a single one, which does everything you seem unwilling to have done yourself. If you do not understand what is happening, and how it works, after all my advice in the previously deleted answer and comment text, please start studying the scripting language before you use the code of other people, _(this is for your own benefit security). I am not here to provide a full tutor/support role for you, simply because I've given some of my time to assist you with one question._ Thank you.