# Bat file to list files, using semicolon delimiter?

Tags: string, windows, batch-file, cmd, directory

So far I have this:

```
@ECHO OFF

dir *.txt /c /b /on > content.txt
```

Which gives output:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

But I need it like this, separated with semicolon on each line:

```
file1.txt;
file2.txt;
file3.txt;
```

I assume I probably need to write for loop and add string ";" somewhere, but I don't know where or how to do this. Or is there a way to just set a specific delimiter?

Edit:

My usecase changed, I thought it would be better if there are files in subfolders listed as well, but "/" should be replaced with space " ".

Example output:

```
file1.txt;
file2.txt;
subfolder1 file1.txt;
subfolder2 file1.txt;
```

Note that I do not want the full parent path, only subfolders.

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window, type `dir /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key to read its help and usage information. You will notice that the `/c` option is of no use to you! Please then type `for /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key to learn how to use a `for` loop. I've included an answer which should achieve your aim, using that information, and doing so in the most efficient and robust way.

Answer (score 2):

Quick single line [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) answer:

```sh
@(For /F Tokens^=*^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('Dir "*.txt" /A:-D /B /O:N 2^>NUL') Do @Echo %%G;) 1>"content.log"
```

…and in [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd):

```sh
(For /F Tokens^=*^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %G In ('Dir "*.txt" /A:-D /B /O:N 2^>NUL') Do @Echo %G;) 1>"content.log"
```

I have decided to output to a `.log` file, so that the listing doesn't include itself.

Please use the built-in help to learn how each command works.

*When you read the help information, please be aware that a 'simple' `for` loop will not pick up all files, it will ignore all hidden files for instance. Also despite any first impressions you may have from testing, the order of files returned, depends upon both the file system and type. The `dir` command is the most efficient way of ensuring that sort order.*

---

**[EDIT /]**

Here is a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) solution, *(as that's what you posted as an answer)*, for your **New and completely different question**.

```sh
@(For /F Tokens^=*^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('Dir "*.txt" /A:-D /B /O:N /S 2^>NUL') Do @(Set "FileName=%%~dpG" & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion & Set "Filename=!FileName:~,-1!" & For %%H In ("!FileName:%__CD__%=!") Do @EndLocal & Echo %%~H %%~nxG;)) 1>"content.log"
```

*In future, when you have existing answers to your asked question, do not change that question when not only the main command is different, but the intended result format too.*

Comment: `Tokens=*` is not necessary when `delims=` is specified. I would not use the unquoted and so hard-to-understand syntax for `for /F` if not absolutely necessary, which is not the case here (`eof` could easily be deactivated by `eof=|` since `|` cannot occur in file names)…

Comment: It may not be necessary @aschipfl, but it is apparently quicker to use both than to just use delims on its own. This was discovered over on DosTips, some time ago. Feel free to search it, _(I believe Mofi did, a week or so ago, when they made the same comment to my use of both, and later confirmed it to be true.)_. I did state that I was posting the most efficient and robust method, and therefore included it, _because the speed is proprtional to the efficiency_.

Comment: Hm… I was quite sure to remember a contrary post on DosTips (but an old one by user npocmaka, when I am not mistaken). Anyway, using both options is certainly not wrong, and I consider it as matter of taste for now. I will surely look up Mofi's post on DosTips soon…

Comment: @aschipfl, I think Mofi's comments may have been below [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70511282), and they have since cleaned them up. I'm afraid that you may need to check with Mofi, for that confirmation, or even whether the information Mofi and I had read, _(I think it was by jeb)_, has subsequently been superseded by what you had read by npocmaka.

Comment: @TaaviViikman, type `dir /?` into a Command Prompt window and read the output usage information; you will find out that `/A` filters attributes, that attribute `D` means *Directory*, and that a preceding `-` inverts the filter, so `-D` means *NOT a Directory*, returning only *files*…

Comment: @aschipfl But it already has (*.txt) in it, so it seems redundant, does not make any difference in this use case. No?

Comment: @Radiowaves, I'm not sure what your above comment is in reference to, since it appears that an earlier comment of yours was deleted before I had read it. However in relation to what I can read, there is absolutely nothing to stop you using `.txt` at the end of any directory name string! BTW, out of courtesy only, I have edited my above answer to include a [[tag:batch-file]] solution for your new question.

Comment: @Compo, it seems the asker has changed their user name, who asked for the purpose of `/A:D` under their former name…

Answer (score 0):

a Simple `for` loop will do:

```
@(for %%i in (*.txt) do @echo %%i;)>"content.txt"
```

That will however also echo the content of `contents.txt` to itself if it exists, so you can exclude it.

```
@(for %%i in (*.txt) do @if /i not "%%~i" == "content.txt" @echo %%i;)>"content.txt"
```

if the plan is to iterate through subdirs as well, run `for /R`

Comment: It should be mentioned that the order of returned files depend on the file system here, whilst `dir /B /O:N` (as used in the question) does not…

Comment: 100% correct, @aschipfl, but the default sort oder is file name, unless OP requires a different sort order which will make my answer void.

Comment: On NTFS, the sort order is by name (although treating extended characters differently than `dir /O:N`). On FAT, items are basically ordered by creation date/time. It now depends on the asker what they need…

Comment: @aschipfl, yes, but the odds of fat being the FS is not so... phat? `:D`

Comment: It is not possible unless you changed my code.

Comment: It `IS` possible if OP executed your code directly from the prompt. (OP: `%%i` is correct *as a batchfile line* but `%i` is required if you are executing directly from the prompt. Of course, the entire purpose of batch is to avoid the error-prone process of perpetually re-typing the code)

Comment: @Magoo, correcr yes, but the question is asking about `Batch-file`,  so I am expecting OP to use this in that context.

Answer (score -1):

I found a partial solution to list subfolders, excluding parent path. It is not perfect (for loop is not accurate as mentioned in above comments, neither I am happy with pushd command), but works. I left "space" in place of `\` because thats how I need it.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd "c:\users\documents\"
(
  for /r %%a in (*.txt) do (
    set x=%%a
    set x=!x:%cd%=!;
    echo !x:\= !
  )
)>filelist.log
popd
```

Code explanation:

First I remove the parent path with `set x=!x:%cd%=!;` (exclamation marks replace the `%`, see `enabledelayedexpansion` help) and then remove the slashes when echoing.

Comment: Please note, as implied already in the answer I had provided for you well in advance of you submitting this, that  a `For /R` loop does not retrieve all files, _(files with certain attributes are ignored)_.

Comment: I predict you'll have problems with directorynames containing the usual suspects - especially `=`. Also, for the result `one two three four.txt`, this could be reported for a file named `one two three four.txt` or `one two\three four.txt` or `one two three\four.txt` or `one\two\three\four.txt` (amongst other possibilities). How do you propose to distinguish between them.

Comment: My use case has to disregard filename with spaces. I have a separate batch script that removes spaces from file names. I did not include it in this batch because: 1) adds bulk; 2) I do not know how. Otherwise good question to which I do not know the answer.
`-` and `=` are problems yes, I just go with not having such folder names, its for specific application anyway. Otherwise solution would be great.

I might disregard this altogether and make a different structured file that points to files.